# AMCharts - unable to get Line graph to draw

Tags: amcharts

I have a line graph drawing using data created like so:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 366; i++) {
    visits += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 10);
    data.push({ date: new Date(2018, 0, i), value: visits });
}
```

The rest of the options set look like:

```
__this._chart.data = data;

var dateAxis = __this._chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.axisFills.template.disabled = true;
dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = true;

var valueAxis = __this._chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 35;
valueAxis.renderer.axisFills.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = true;

var series = __this._chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
```

This draws a random line for the whole year and it works.

We dont want to show every day, we want to show monthly data. So I have data that when processed shows up in the form:

```
{
    category: Mon Oct 31 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
    column-1: 50
}
```

Theres only 9 of them and they cover up to January 2019, so there would be huge gaps between the data points. the object name of category is different to date but I set the series' dateX = "category".

So my question is, can the line graph be used to do monthly data where there could be gaps in the data?

If so, how do I get it to work? I use the rest of the options the exact same as the test that is working, except for hte changed values of series' dateX and valueY.

Comment: I don't understand how your monthly data is calculated. Can you please explain more?

Comment: Basically we have a bunch of deals. Each deal had a close date. So I want to chart how much deals have been worth per month based on their close date. So I get the deals and creat a map with date as the key and then the sum of all deals for that month as the value. The data before is ones for a given accout which is why there are gaps

Comment: To clarify. When I store the date as the key I make it the last day of the month so all deals from the same month have the same key

Comment: So basically you just have a date/category for the month, and a field for the count? Wouldn't that be similar to this demo: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/chart-with-gaps-in-data/? And there is a trick you need to know in order to draw gaps. You can read through this issue here: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/636

Comment: Thanks for this. Im having a mess around with whats there. I have a question though. If i wanted to change the data so it showed months from different years, how would I do that? So say I want to start in Jun 2016, show data  for each month up to June 2017, How would I structure the objects in the data to represent month and year? Tried one or two things, still at it, but so far, no luck

Comment: I found this: https://live.amcharts.com/UxZGR/ but when i go to the live editor it shows the code from AM charts 3.

Comment: I might misunderstand your problem/question but wouldn't it be as simple as grouping your data by month? You just need to group by your time and only get the year and month out of it? I guess the data you input to amchart would look like a collection of `{ date: "2018-01", count: 100 }, { date: "2018-02", count: 122 }, ...`

Comment: Yeah, thats how I had it and it wasnt working, but then earlier today I found a bug that might have been causing this to fail. gonna give it a shot again soon

Comment: Post that problem out instead of this. And show us what you have done, and create a demo using jsfiddles..